Tabbed page with settings + saving, discarding changes - Best practices?
I have a configuration page with many settings across 8 tabs. Since this is a tabbed page, I allow users to move freely from one tab to another and make changes as they wish. I also provide a set of buttons for discarding changes. If a user leaves a tab while the form is "dirty" (i.e., changes have been made), I add a semi-transparent red dot on the "dirty" tab to indicate that changes have been made.
I have a few questions about this approach:

Should this page be editable right from the start, or is it better to provide an "Edit" button (second design)? Users frequently make changes to various tabs.
If users perform a critical action, like deleting something important, should the item be deleted immediately after clicking "Delete" and confirming, or should it only be deleted after they click the "Save" button?
I would also like advice on the text for the buttons. Users can discard changes they have made within the current tab during this visit, discard changes across all tabs, or save all settings. Can you suggest the best wording for these options?



There is no need to add extra controls during form edit. The simpler the form the better. It will help if you get rid of all non-essential controls like delete buttons and status indicators. Of course, run some tests with the primary users and get quick feedback. User testing at this stage (before diving deeper to detailed design) is essential to determine the right direction in terms of page layout, global navigation and information architecture.



I don't think there is a right or wrong answer to this, because best practices work well when you are dealing with simpler scenarios where it makes sense to keep things as simple and consistent as possible to ensure that the interface is easy to understand or learn.
Since you are already going beyond what would be considered a small number of tabs, I would say that you need to think about whether there will be more items (i.e. tabs and tab items) added to the interface, and what is the best way to provide a consistent experience for the users.
As to your questions:

I can see a good reason for having an edit button if there are a lot of potential actions that are destructive (i.e. removes data), or if you don't provide additional confirmation for destructive actions.
It seems unnecessary to double up with a delete confirmation and then a save action. But again you have to use your best judgement based on all of the options provided in all of the tabs to make things consistent and simpler for the user. If there are a lot of these types of settings, and the user is likely to set them often, then doubling up may not be very efficient.
This should be labelled appropriately depending on what you decide for the first two questions.

